# How to view model outputs for a Keras NN Regression model?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


dataframe=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/joe/Desktop/BIS/bon.csv', header=0)
dataset=dataframe.values

#splitting into input and output variables
X=dataset[:,0:11]
Y=dataset[:,11]


#defining baseline model
def baseline_model():
    #creating model
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(11, input_dim=11, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1,kernel_initializer='normal'))
    #compiling model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    #testing model
    return model

#fixing random seed
seed=7
np.random.seed(seed)

estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
kfold=KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results=cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv=kfold)
print("Results: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

I want to compare the true values (stored in Y) to the model's predicted values, how do I do it?

I have tried 
    print (model.layers[-1].output) just before `return model` in the `def baseline model` block. But this is what I get as output:

```
Tensor("dense_42/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("dense_44/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("dense_46/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("dense_48/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("dense_50/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("dense_52/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("dense_54/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("dense_56/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("dense_58/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("dense_60/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Results: 0.09 (0.09) MSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not getting the values in `model.layers[-1].output` is because this is just the model structure (graph), not the session which actually runs the model.

You can simply use the function `cross_val_predict` instead of `cross_val_score` to get the predictions, I think:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm!
How should I go about getting the individual layer outputs then?

Comment: Also, how would I get the corresponding 'true values' to the predictions, so as to show a non ML person the close-ness of the predictions?

Comment: The true values are Y.

Comment: In that case, will this model be predicting values for every element in Y? Wouldn't that then mean that the entire data-set was used for training, and the results too would be on the entire training set and not the test set?

Comment: That's the point of cross-validation: let's say you have 5-fold CV, data is split into parts 1,2,3,4,5. In the first step, you train on 1...4 and evaluate on 5. In the next step, you train on 1,2,3,5 and evaluate on 4, etc. That way, you get predictions for the entire dataset.

Comment: About intermediate layers: I'm no Keras expert but there is a FAQ answer you can follow. https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer